# TextInput must not allow special characters and numbers

Tags: react-native

**Description :**
I want only alphabets to be entered in textinput not symbols and special characters.
If there any prop or way to do that other than onChangeText function call and using regex in IOS and android in react native

Because in native android and IOS has property to allow only alphabets and number .

for ex: android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "

**React-native info :**
react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5

**Steps To Reproduce :**
1)Add a TextInput component.

**Expected Results :**

TextInput must allow only alphabets not special characters and numbers .

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do it manually but i have personally found using Formik very helpful and time saving.

```
      if (!values.email) {
    errors.email = 'Required';
} else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)) {
    errors.email = 'Invalid email address';
}
```

it uses the above approach which is intuitive and easy to debug. 
https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/